# How to simplifythe expression (to closed form)

Tags: calculus

How to simplifythe expression (to closed form)?

$$\frac { \sum_{i=0}^{a-1} (b+i) \binom{i+b-1}{b-1} p^b(1-p)^i}{ \sum_{i=0}^{a-1} \binom{i+b-1}{b-1} p^b(1-p)^i}$$

I have tried to worj with the binomial parts, but it seems like I cannot really combine two sums into one.

Comment: Are you sure you copied the problem correctly?  $p^b$ is completely extraneous.

Comment: @DanielV I have just updated the problem. This is a probability calculation, so q=1-p, but yes, I'm sure that p has to be there

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps one thought would be to write
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{a-1} (b+i) \binom{i+b-1}{b-1} p^bq^i}
     {\sum_{i=0}^{a-1} \binom{i+b-1}{b-1} p^bq^i}
&= \frac{\sum_{i=0}^{a-1} b \binom{i+b-1}{b-1} p^bq^i
      + \sum_{i=0}^{a-1} i \binom{i+b-1}{b-1} p^bq^i}
     {\sum_{i=0}^{a-1} \binom{i+b-1}{b-1} p^bq^i} \\
&= b + \frac{\sum_{i=0}^{a-1} i \binom{i+b-1}{b-1} p^bq^i}
     {\sum_{i=0}^{a-1} \binom{i+b-1}{b-1} p^bq^i}
\end{split}
$$

and note that if the lower sum is $f(q)$ you can compute the upper sum as a flavor of $qf'(q)$.